# Extracting key from json string having null value

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

I have following function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."test"(
    _data text)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    
AS $BODY$
    
    declare _sdate date:= null;
    
    begin
        
        select json_extract_path(_data:: json , 'sdate') into _sdate;
        select _data:: json -> 'sdate' into _sdate;
    END;
$BODY$;
```

I tried both way but it throws syntax error when sdate is null

I am calling like

```
select public."test"($${
        "sdate":null
      }$$)
```

but when I give sdate value it is working

```
select public."test"($${
        "sdate":"2020-1-01"
      }$$)
```

I also tried explicity parsing like

```
select _data:: json -> 'sdate'::date into _sdate;
```

But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in your function. The first one being that you are not returning anything as you are missing a `return` statement.

Your expression: `_data:: json -> 'sdate'::date` is not working because the cast operator `::` binds more strongly than the `->' operator and thus you are casting` 'sdate'`to a date, not the result of the`->` operator.

You should also declare the function parameter as `json`, rather than casting it inside the function. And you need to use `->>` to return the value as a text value because there is no direct cast from `json` to `date`.

You are casting the result to a date, but your function is declared to return `integer` which also doesn't match.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."test"(_data json)
  RETURNS date --<< here
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  stable
AS 
$BODY$
declare 
  _sdate date := null;
begin
  _sdate := (_data ->> 'sdate')::date;
  return _sdate;
END;
$BODY$;
```

---

The way you formatted your code suggests that you think `declare` is needed for each variable. But `declare` starts a block that can contain multiple declarations. declarations, it's not something that needs to be repeated for each variable.

Comment: I have given the only part that is not working function... might be some typo while preparing, but the actual problem i am facing is when i pass null in date key in json it throws error but when I pass the value it works

Comment: I am getting error invalid input syntax for type date: "null", and this exactly here "select _data:: json -> 'sdate' into _sdate"

Comment: Well, if you only show part of the problem, how do you expect to get the answer to your real problem? My function works without problems with a NULL input: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d9da1522937e723b424e7b620d43e6fa

Comment: Thanks with the help of your fiddle I found my function working.... just curious to know if you could help... the diff was I was using -> rather than ->> and ::date casting at the end not working with ->

Comment: I have explained that in the second and third paragraph of my answer